# iPhone 5S wallpaper zooming when set through MDM despite being correct resolution

Tags: iphone, mobile-device-management, wallpaper

I have some devices managed through MDM (JAMF) and a 640 x 1136 wallpaper that I want to set through the MDM interface as the home/lock screen background. Unfortunately, pretty much every time I set it it comes out zoomed in.

I have set up the restrictions on the configuration such that the user cannot change the wallpapers.

This may be relevant: https://jamfnation.jamfsoftware.com/featureRequest.html?id=3232

Doesn't seem to be a way to turn it off properly, but perhaps if I set the resolution of the wallpaper image to something bigger than my target, it will show up properly. Rather than figure this out by trial and error, perhaps someone will know an appropriate resolution to use?

Answer (score 1):

I have used an mdm like JAMF and facing same issue like you, i have use this link : http://iosres.com to find my resolution.

You will find all right resolution for all iOS devices.

Hope it will help you.
Br